# Scaling Google Slides iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, moodle

I´m fairly new to web design and I'm currently creating an online course for my students on Moodle. I would like to scale the iframe content of an embedded Google Slides presentation according to the parent window. I found a solution for this on [responsive-google-slides](https://chrisyee.ca/blog/responsive-google-slides/):

```
.google-slides-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.google-slides-container iframe{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Then wrap the Google Slides code in  tags:

```
<div class="google-slides-container">
    [Your Google Slides Embed iFrame Code]
</div>
```

My problem is that I don't have administrative rights (no access to header of documents, CSS style-sheets etc.) on Moodle. I'm looking for a way to include these attributes in the body of a document. I tried to include style tags but Moodle always overwrites them. Is there any way to create the two classes "google-slides-container" and "google-slides iframe" with JavaScript or include these attributes in div tags? Many thanks in advance, Marcus

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me:

```
<div class="embed-container"
 style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 59.27%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%;">
 <iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
  src="[Enter src from Google Slides Embed iFrame Code]" frameborder="0" width="960" height="569" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

You may change the padding-bottom percentage value as required.